# add tooltip to link_to_unless_current helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tooltip

I have tried with something like:

```
 <%= link_to_unless_current t('.en'), :locale => 'en', :rel => "tooltip", :title => "one title"%>
```

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I need use [twitter bootstrap tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips).

**But it's not working.**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [doc page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless_current), the format should be:

```rb
link_to_unless_current(name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Have you tried:

```rb
<%= link_to_unless_current t('.en', locale: 'en'), {}, { rel: "tooltip", title: "one title" } %>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's incorrect. I have added the code that is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, i added an extra {}.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery tooltips for sexier views: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current  t('.en'), {:locale => 'en'}, { rel: "tooltip", title: "one title" } %>
```

Regards!